# IOS application in background mode

Tags: ios

If my application is pushed to the background, is there a way to guarantee some minimal CPU resource allocation for it ( ~ 5-10%) ?

I use "location" value for UIBackgroundMode attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can ask iOS to give you a few cycles to do something after your sent to the background using this function on UIApplication:

```
beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
```

It is also possible to register your App for certain services and to be notified when they occur while you are in the background... but iOS does not allow you to get some % of cycles to do anything while in the background.

The documentation addressing the details is here:
[Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)